# Multinomial Probability Exercise

Tags: probability, self-study, multinomial-distribution

I have this problem:

Among 30 students in a group, 6 students received grade "5" for the exam, 10 students - "4", 9 students - "3", the rest - "2". Find the probability that 3 students, called to the blackboard, got grade “2” for the exam.

So I easily solved it because it's a multinomial distribution.

```
|grade| 5   |  4   |  3  |  2  |
--------------------------------
|prob | 6/30| 10/30| 9/30| 5/30|
```

x2 = number of students who got grade "2"

P(x2 = 3) = 3!/(0!0!0!3!) * (6/30)^0 (10/30)^0 (9/30)^0 (5/30)^3 = (5/30)^3 = 0.0046

But the correct answer is 0.002. Is it a mistake or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Think of differences between sampling with and without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we have a 3 spot, _ _ _

all the spot has to be filled by only those who obtained grade "2"
since, we not concerned about other graded student, we only take 5 students with grade "2".

$$P(first spot)= 5/30$$
$$P(second spot)= 4/29$$
$$P(third spot)= 3/28$$

$$result = (5/30)*(4/29)*(3/28)=(1/406)=0.002463054187$$

Comment: There is no "we have a 3 spot" in OP. "called to the blackboard" means "we have a 3 spot"?

Comment: since, 3 students were called to the blackboard. I meant those 3 spot for those 3 student position.

Comment: I think the original question should be "Find the probability that 3 students, called 3 students to the blackboard, got grade “2” for the exam." and your answer is correct. If called more than 3 students, for example 4, then your answer is incorrect. So original question is not clear.